# Disable non-SWT window while SWT dialog showing

Tags: java, swt, lwjgl

I'm mixing SWT with a non-SWT window (formerly an AWT window but I'm now using a native GLFW window). When I call `fileDialog.show()`, I would like the file dialog to get the full application context, where it is drawn on top of the existing non-SWT window, and the non-SWT window cannot be clicked. i.e., the same behavior as when using AWT with an AWT FileDialog.

However, when I show the SWT FileDialog, it still allows me to click the other window and bring that window to front.

Here's how I set up my app. I'm using LWJGL 3 (via LibGDX), which in turn creates a native window through a GLFW binding. And this is part of the reason I'm using SWT...GLFW does not support AWT or Swing.

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    //...
    new Lwjgl3Application(app, config); //starts an OpenGL loop in a native GLFW window
    prepareSWT();
}

    static void prepareSWT (){
        swtThread = new Thread(new Runnable (){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swtDisplay = new Display();
                swtShell = new Shell(swtDisplay);

                while (!swtDisplay.isDisposed()) {
                    if (!swtDisplay.readAndDispatch())
                        swtDisplay.sleep();
                }
                swtDisplay.dispose();
            }
        });

        swtThread.start();
    }


    public static void showSWTFileChooserDialog (final FileChooserResult fileChooserResult){
        swtDisplay.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog fileChooser =
                        new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog(swtShell, SWT.OPEN);

                fileChooser.open();
                String filename = fileChooser.getFileName();

                if (filename == null || filename.equals("")){
                    fileChooserResult.file = null;
                } else {
                    fileChooserResult.file = new File(fileChooser.getFilterPath(), filename);
                }
                fileChooserResult.ready = true;
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm at a loss for how to get the FileDialog to be forced on top of the non-SWT window.

Comment: To the shell constructor you could try to pass the style bit SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL, not sure if it works in your case tho

Comment: Doesn't help. Thanks.

Comment: I've also tried SWT.ON_TOP which puts it on top as I like, but it puts it on top of all other apps as well, even if I switch to other apps (at least in Windows 7).

Comment: It occurred to me that maybe an acceptable solution would be to pull the dialog to front if the other window is brought to focus or clicked, etc. But I don't see a way to pull the SWT dialog to front. If the window were minimizable, maybe you could do `shell.setMinimized(true);
                            shell.setMinimized(false);
                            shell.setActive();`, but file dialogs are not minimizable.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `SWT.SYSTEM_MODAL` style on the Shell will block input to all applications' windows on the system.

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html#SYSTEM_MODAL